# Regex to take string from the end

Tags: php, regex

i have this string

```
"Kuala Lumpur   <br/>
    53000           Setapak"
```

i want to get the last substring "setapak", but sometimes the string also looks like

```
pantai jerjak   <br/>
                Gelugor
```

how do i get that last substring with regex? i have tried to strip the digits with \d+ but not working since the string always different (with no digit).

is there a way to get string from the end with regex, like negative in substr?

Comment: So you only want to extract `Setapak` and `Gelugor` ?

Comment: yes, exactly. with a note that last substring could be from 1 to n of length.

Comment: Have you tried `.*\s+(.*)$` - this shoud give you verything after the last whitespace

Comment: This is too simple, why don't you [learn](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/) before asking/reaching for help ?

Comment: yes Sir, i have learned before i ask but i hit the wall. it is might simple for you, but not for me ;)

thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you need:

```
\w+$
```

`\w` is the metacharacter for "word character", which includes letters, numbers, and underscore.  `+` says "one or more", and the `$` says "end of line"  So you could interpret this in English as: "match a word consisting of letters, numbers, and the underscore character at the end of the line."

If you want only letters, you could do this instead:

```
[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "Kuala Lumpur   <br/> 53000           Setapak";
$str = preg_replace("/\s\w*$/", " setapak", $str);
echo $str;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Kuala Lumpur   <br/> 53000           setapak
```

(switched the capital "s" with lower-case).